# Creating constructor and send to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ravendb

Im creating a pedigree-tree for my dogs and Im having som trouble.
I have three classes:

The dog-class:

```
 public class Dog
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Merit1 { get; set; }
        public string Merit2 { get; set; }           
    }
```

The Pedigree class:

```
 public class Pedigree
    {
        public Dog Father { get; set; }
        public Dog GrandFather { get; set; }
        public Dog GrandMother { get; set; }
        public Dog GrandFathersFather { get; set; }
        etc....
```

The Class i want to send to the view, here with harcoded values just to get me started:

```
public class DogContentPage : ContentPage
    {

        public DogContentPage()
        {
            Name = "The Dog";
            Age = "4";


            Pedigree = new Pedigree();
            {

                mother = new Dog {Name = "Chanelle", Merit1 = "Universal"};
                father = new Dog {Name = "dfdfdf", Merit1 = "dfdfdfdfdf"};

            };

        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Age { get; set; }
        public Dog mother { get; set; }
        public Dog father { get; set; }  
    }
```

In the view im trying something simple like this:

```
    @model EmmysBlog_Core.Models.Dog.DogContentPage

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>@Model.Name</h1>

<p>@Model.Pedigree.Mother.Name</p>
<p>@Model.Pedigree.Mother.Merit1</p>
```

The error I get is, object not set to instance...
What I want is to be able to display the properties for my dogs...what am i missing?

Comment: Where do you actually create an instance and pass it to the view?  Also note that your casing is wrong and the code you've provided won't actually compile.  Please share actual code samples to more accurately determine the problem.

Comment: Which line throws an exception? Show the piece of code where you instantiated your model.

Comment: I updated the view-part, the exception gets thrown at:
<p>@Model.Pedigree.Mother.Name</p>

Comment: See Edit for contrller

Comment: The values in the ctor gets saved in the db but I cant seem to acces them in the view...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Pedigree` constructor you need to instantiate the property classes as well, they are not instantiated so it throws **null reference exception**:

```
public Pedigree()
{
    this.Mother = new Dog{Name = "Chanelle", Merit1 = "Universal"};
    this.Father = new Dog{Name = "dfdfdf", Merit1 = "dfdfdfdfdf"};
    this.GrandFather = new Dog();
    this.GrandMother = new Dog();
    this.GrandFathersFather = new Dog();
}
```

In your code also there are mistakes, in your way this should be like this:

```
Pedigree obj = new Pedigree
{
    Mother = new Dog {Name = "Chanelle", Merit1 = "Universal"};
    Father = new Dog {Name = "dfdfdf", Merit1 = "dfdfdfdfdf"};
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ehsan! You saved me again =). For some reason I thought that all initializations only was only be done in the model you pass to the view...

Comment: the inner classes as properties also need to be instantiated in constructor or the way you were doing